# I want to put a webpage inside jquery dialog and get the URL of the webpage inside the dialog when the dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a webpage to be open inside a Jquery dialog box. Lets take the webpage google search page. And when the user is done searching he just close the dialog box.So when the dialog box is closed I want the url of the search page inside the dialog box.How can i do this.? Or is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might haven gotten it wrong.. But to clear things out:
You want to popup a window with the help of jQuery. That window will act like a mini-browser. Where user goes to a URL, when user closes the popup window, you want the URL to be used in some way.

In that case, maybe you want to use **[Lytebox](http://dolem.com/lytebox/)** (click on the "Search Google!" example.) Now modify it a little, to get the URL. Should not be hard.

If this is what you meant, then we can go from there..

Comment: Some part u understood right. But let me explain again. In the overlay I want to appear some webpage. So definately there is no URL box.

Comment: Define URL box. Do you mean URL bar like in a browser? Whats different in the example of Lytebox?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you would have to do is three things.

One is finding a dialog box type that allows display of iframes.

Two is using an iframe inside the dialog box, to display the webpage.

Three is: on a click event (for example on the closing button of the dialog) you should get the iframe's window.location like so:

```
alert( $('iframeId').contents().get(0).location.href );
```

If he closed the dialog before hitting the page he searched for, this is not working anyways.

Be aware though, that this violates XSS-rules (Cross-Site Scripting) and is to be avoided.
I personally would strongly advise against implementing such a solution. It breaks your page's overall style, if you're implementing iframes and also there's already complete, stylable solutions for that to implement on your page.

Comment: do u know any working example...I don't have much understanding about HTML stuff. May be you can show me using some kind of overlay.

Comment: Actually the page i want to show in dialog box belongs to my website only but the requirement is such that I have to do this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access a url from another domain.

If you use a proxy you can capture all urls but not in a normal web page with jQuery

In the case of google, that is how they do it. All the links on the search page goes to google with the actual url as parameter. for you to do that with google you would proxy a proxy